# How much do mathematicians know?

Tags: soft-question

How much does a good mathematicians know about math? I mean, do mathematicians know the details of every branch of mathematics or they just specialize on a specific branch/topic? And what are the branches and minimum requirements that every mathematicians have to know in order to be one?

Comment: Most mathematicians are very specialized. However, any "professional" mathematician (i.e, has a graduate degree in the subject) knows at least a tiny bit about pretty much every area of math.

Comment: Mathematical knowledge now is so vast, nobody is a broad generalist.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the majority of mathematicians have a bit of exposure to a wide variety of topics so that if they needed a certain idea/tool from some other branch they can  find the material and relevant information relatively fast.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373333/do-most-mathematicians-know-most-topics-in-mathematics) is similar to your question.